# how to calculate surface area of a pyramid in python?

Tags: python, methods, computer-science

How to calculate the surface area of a pyramid in python using the formula below?

Area = base^2 + base √(base^2 + 4 ∙ height^2)

```
import math
def main():

    # Your main code goes here
    b = eval(input("Enter the base: "))
    h = eval(input("Enter the height: "))

    print("The surface area of the pyramid is : ",Area)


# Create a method here to calculate pyramid area

# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓


import math

def calcPyramid(b,h):

    Area = math.pow(b * b + b (math.sqrt(b * b + 4 * h * h)))
    return Area

##########################################################
# This will run your main method when we load the project.
# Do not change this `if` statement or your program will fail all tests on 
Gradescope!
###########################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In your calculation you have: `b * b + b (...)`. To python the `b(...)` looks like a function call where you are expecting `b` to be the name of a function. Did you mean: `b * b + b * ( ... )`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `*` operator to indicate multiplication (in your case, `b` times the square root).

Answer (score 0):

```
# Python 3 program to find the 
# surface area Of Square pyramid 

# function to find the surface area 
def surfaceArea(b, s): 

    return 2 * b * s + pow(b, 2) 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    b = 3
    s = 4

    # surface area of the square pyramid 
    print(surfaceArea(b, s))
```